# Is there an equivalent of a "possibly undefined" value in a template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, undefined

I have code in a Vue component that relies on values that are not guaranteed to be defined (but they become defined later). I wanted to use in `<template>` a `.value?` entry, similar to what I use in JS:

```
<div v-for="n in wantedHours.length - displayedHours?.length" :key="n"></div>
```

(`wantedHours` is always defined, `displayedHours` may not be). This does not work as `?` is unexpected there.

I solved the problem by having in the template

```
<div v-for="n in wantedHours.length - nrDisplayedHours" :key="n"></div>
```

and in the script part

```
const nrDisplayedHours = computed(() => displayedHours.value !== undefined ? displayedHours.value.length : 0)
```

**This works fine** but I wanted to make sure there is no simpler way to do that (notably with having a "possibly undefined" value flag (such as `?`) but another solution would be great as well.

Comment: Elvis operator is not enough, you can't substract undefined value It's something like `displayedHours?.length ?? 0`. The whole `wantedHours.length - displayedHours?.length` part belongs to script block, spreading logic between it an a template randomly results in messy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript (and TypeScript), the optional chaining (?.) is a useful feature for accessing nested object properties without having to explicitly check if each reference is valid. Unfortunately, Vue's template syntax doesn't directly support optional chaining.

Your approach using a computed property to handle the potentially undefined value is idiomatic in Vue. It keeps your template clean and allows for better separation of concerns.

However, if you wanted to keep the logic in the template, you could use the ternary conditional (inline if-else) in the template:

```
<div v-for="n in wantedHours.length - (displayedHours ? displayedHours.length : 0)" :key="n"></div>
```

This is essentially what your computed property is doing, but inline in the template.

Hope this helps!